# Program works on ideone but not locally (possible memory error)

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory

https://ideone.com/822Egw

I'm trying to solve a BFS exercise and when I use ideone's compiler it works and prints out "2 4" which is the correct output for this input:

```
7 8
..#...##
.##.....
###.A..A
.#......
.#....A.
...A....
........
```

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 1001

struct node
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int distance;
};

int l, c;
char grid[MAX][MAX], temp;
node clouds[MAX * MAX];
int n_clouds = 0;
int i, u;
int visited[MAX][MAX];
int dx[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
int dy[] = {0, -1, 0, 1};
int n_min, n_max;

inline int max(int a, int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

inline int min(int a, int b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

void read_input()
{
  scanf("%d %d", &l, &c);

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
    for (u = 0; u < c; u++)
    {
      scanf(" %c", &temp);
      grid[i][u] = temp;

      if (temp == '#')
      {
        node cloud;
        cloud.x = u;
        cloud.y = i;

        clouds[n_clouds] = cloud;
        n_clouds++;
      }
    }
  }
}

void bfs(node start)
{
  queue<node> q;
  q.push(start);

  memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);

  while (!q.empty())
  {
    node current = q.front();
    q.pop();

    int x = current.x;
    int y = current.y;
    int distance = current.distance;

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= c || y >= l || visited[y][x])
    {
      continue;
    }

    //printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);

    visited[y][x] = 1;

    if (grid[y][x] == 'A')
    {
      printf("distance: %d\n", distance);

      if (n_min == -1)
        n_min = distance;
      else
        n_min = min(n_min, distance);

      n_max = max(n_max, distance);
      return;
    }

    node node;
    node.distance = distance + 1;

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
      node.x = x + dx[k];
      node.y = y + dy[k];
      q.push(node);

      //printf("node.x = %d, node.y = %d, k = %d\n", node.x, node.y, k);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  read_input();

  n_min = -1;
  n_max = -1;

  for (i = 0; i < n_clouds; i++)
  {
    bfs(clouds[i]);
  }

  printf("%d %d\n", n_min, n_max);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using `g++ file.cpp -o file` to compile and this is the local output on my 4GB of RAM laptop:

```
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
distance: 4196514
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
distance: 4196514
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
4196514 4196516
```

It's very different from ideone's output:

```
distance: 4
distance: 3
distance: 2
distance: 4
distance: 3
distance: 4
distance: 3
distance: 2
distance: 4
distance: 3
2 4
```

I'm guessing this is a memory error of some sort probably caused by the [MAX][MAX] bi-dimensional arrays but I thought I could have [1001][1001] arrays. I need ideas on what's going on. Also, I believe this happens with any input because with this one, I also get weird huge numbers:

```
3 3
#..
...
..A
```

On ideone I get the correct output:

```
distance: 4
4 4
```

This program is supposed to calculate the minimum and the maximum distance from any cloud ('#') to an airport ('A').

Here's valgrind output, I don't think it is reporting any memory error:

```
~/src/oni> valgrind ./nuvemcinzas < nuvemcinzas_input.txt 
==20861== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20861== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20861== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20861== Command: ./nuvemcinzas
==20861== 
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x53954F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400C71: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
==20861== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==20861==    at 0x53937EB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==20861==    by 0x5395837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400C71: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x53937F5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==20861==    by 0x5395837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400C71: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
distance: 4196516
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x400EB9: max(int, int) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400CBA: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
distance: 4196515
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x400C7B: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x400ED5: min(int, int) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400C9F: bfs(node) (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861==    by 0x400E25: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
distance: 4196514
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
distance: 4196514
distance: 4196516
distance: 4196515
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x53954F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400E66: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
==20861== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==20861==    at 0x53937EB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==20861==    by 0x5395837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400E66: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
==20861== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20861==    at 0x53937F5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==20861==    by 0x5395837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==20861==    by 0x539E8D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==20861==    by 0x400E66: main (in /home/david/src/oni/nuvemcinzas)
==20861== 
4196514 4196516
==20861== 
==20861== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20861==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20861==   total heap usage: 49 allocs, 49 frees, 15,896 bytes allocated
==20861== 
==20861== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20861== 
==20861== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20861== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==20861== ERROR SUMMARY: 208 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Try running it under `valgrind`.

Comment: I actually already did, but I didn't post the output. It doesn't seem to report any memory error, but I'm not very experienced with valgrind. One second, let me edit the question.

Comment: @user996056: The `valgrid` output points to quite a few uses of uninitialized variables.

Comment: For future reference, if you build with the `-g` flag the executable will contain debugging information, that can be used by Valgrind (and a debugger or course) to display line numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not initialize the value of distance in your clouds array correctly

Try changing this

```
    node cloud;
    cloud.x = u;
    cloud.y = i;
    clouds[n_clouds] = cloud;
```

to this

```
    node cloud;
    cloud.x = u;
    cloud.y = i;
    cloud.distance = 0;
    clouds[n_clouds] = cloud;
```

Comment: @user996056 Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. Working correctly is one possibility when your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user996056 Some environments (like running in a debugger usually) clears memory for you.